# Blackberry: WebBitmapField center image

Tags: blackberry

http://www.coderholic.com/blackberry-webbitmapfield/

This is a great script for grabbing an image from the web for a Blackberry App. Now I would like to know how to center the returned image. I have tried everything.

This portion of code seems to return the image:

**byte[] dataArray = data.getBytes();

bitmap = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(dataArray, 0,

dataArray.length);

setImage(bitmap);**

This displays the image:

**getimage = new WebBitmapField("http://");
add (getimage);**

Where can I put FIELD_HCENTER to center this thing. 
Please show sample code. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using this WebBitmapField, then you'll need to add a new constructor so that style bits can be passed to the BitmapField:

```
public class WebBitmapField extends BitmapField implements WebDataCallback  
{  
    ...
    public WebBitmapField(String url, long style)  
    {  
        super(style);
        try  
        {  
            Util.getWebData(url, this);  
        }  
        catch (Exception e) {}  
    }  

    public WebBitmapField(String url) 
    {
        this(url, 0L);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place your WebBitmapField in a custom manager and set the position of the field
then u can possibly achieve the center location like:

```
class CustomManager extends Manager
{
    CustomManager()
     {
        super(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
     } 
    sublayout(int width , int height)
     {
       Field field = getField(0);
       layoutChild(field , Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
       setPositionChild(field, (Display.getWidth()- field.getWidth())/2,
           Display.getHeight());

      setExtent( Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
     }
}


In MainScreen use it as:
CustomManager  obj = new CustomManager();
getimage = new WebBitmapField("http://");
obj.add(getimage );
add(obj);
```

Comment: its an object of WebBitmapField

Comment: can you please help me and answer here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859003/is-there-any-lazyloader-for-images-to-load-image-in-listfield-in-blackberry/13860529#13860529